# PHP Tokens From a String

Tags: php, tokenize

Let's say you have a string that looks like this:
`token1 token2 tok3`

And you want to get all of the tokens (specifically the strings between the spaces), AND ALSO their position (offset) and length).

So I would want a result that looks something like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'value'=>'token1'
        'offset'=>0
        'length'=>6
    ),
    array(
        'value'=>'token2'
        'offset'=>7
        'length'=>6
    ),
    array(
        'value'=>'tok3'
        'offset'=>14
        'length'=>4
    ),
)
```

I know that this can be done by simply looping through the characters of the string and I can simply write a function to do this.

I am wondering, does PHP have anything built-in that will do this efficiently or at least help with part of this?

I am looking for suggestions and appreciate any help given.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) with the *PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE* flag:

```
$str = 'token1 token2 tok3';
preg_match_all('/\S+/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches);
```

Then you just need to replace the items in `$matches[0]` like this:

```
function update($match) {
    return array( 'value' => $value[0], 'offset' => $value[1], 'length' => strlen($value[0]));
}   
array_map('update', $matches[0]);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a simpler way, in most respects.  You'll have a more basic result, but with much less work put in.

Assuming you have `tokena tokenb tokenc` stored in $data

```
$tokens = explode(' ', $data);
```

Now you have an array of tokens separated by spaces.  They will be in order, so $tokens[0] = tokena, $tokens[1] = tokenb, etc.  You can very easily get the length of any given item by doing `strlen($tokens[$index]);`  If you need to know how many tokens you were passed, use `$token_count = count($tokens);`

Not as sophisticated, but next to no work to get it.

Comment: Thank for the answer.  It still does not give the position in the string.  Assume that there is more than one space between each token.  The first solution (to use PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) was more what I was looking for, but thank you.

Comment: Oh, you wanted the character offset of each token, not just an index on each.  I misunderstood.  Yeah, @Gumbo is probably a lot closer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `explode()`, which will give you an array of tokens from the string, and `strlen()` to count the number of characters in the string. As far as I know, I don't think there is a PHP function to tell you where an element is in an array.

To get around the last problem, you could use a counter variable that loops through the `explod()`ed array (`foreach()` for `for()`) and gives each sub-array in the new data it's position.

Someone please correct my if I'm wrong.

James

Comment: http://us3.php.net/array_search -> array_search - Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

Comment: @Rocket - thanks! I had actually come across that function a while ago, but couldn't find it when I wrote this post so I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

I like the first answer the most - to use PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE.  In case anyone else is interested, I ended up writing something that does this as well, although I am going to accept the first answer.

Thank you everybody for helping!

```
function get_words($string) {
    $string_chars = str_split($string);

    $words = array();
    $curr_offset = 0;

    foreach($reduced_string_chars as $offset=>$char) {
        if ($char == ' ') {
            if ($length) $words[] = array('offset'=>$curr_offset,'length'=>$length,'value'=>implode($value_array));

            $curr_offset = $offset;
            $length = 0;
            $value_array = array();
        }
        else {
            $length++;
            $value_array[] = $char;
        }

    }

    return $words;
}
```